# scp over login server

Tags: ssh, remote-access, scp

I need to copy files from a remote folder on machine S1 to my local machine L1 using scp. However, I have access to S1 only via a login server X1 (where I cannot store the files and cannot use nc). What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What kind of login server is X1? If you have a ssh account in that server, you may be able to create SSH tunnels

Comment: This question is a duplicate of another one. Check this out: http://superuser.com/q/479692/222635